# Php, what to use instead of create_function()?

Tags: php, lambda

I know the differences between `Lambda` and `Closures`. I dont want to use `Closure` since it gets its environment, and `var_dump()`-ing it would result a tons of output. Using lambda with `create_function()` looked a good idea, but its getting deprecated. Then what to use to create functions that not aware in their enviromnent?

Comment: PHP anonymous functions **do not** capture their environment. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) says: *"Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct."*

Answer (score 2):

Use [static closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static):

> As of PHP 5.4, anonymous functions may be declared statically. This
>   prevents them from having the current class automatically bound to
>   them. Objects may also not be bound to them at runtime.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $func = static function() {
            var_dump($this);
        };
        $func();
    }
};
new Foo();

?>
```

yields

```
Notice: Undefined variable: this in %s on line %d
NULL
```